# eclipse shutdown button can not shutdown embedded tomcat used fo spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, embedded-tomcat-8

I'm using embedded tomcat in my spring boot application. 
I tun application with goal below:

```
clean spring-boot:run
```

and it runs with no error. I use eclipse shutdown button to shut it down. 
second time i try to run it i get this :

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) on project cpanel: Failed to clean project: Failed to delete XXXXXXXXX\target\classes\hibernate\security\user\User.hbm.xml -> [Help 1]
```

it sims tomcat can't delete target for next time. whats wrong with my tomcat? 
Am i doing some thing wrong?

My server configuration in application.yml:

```
server:
compression:
    enabled: true
port: 8080
servlet-path: /rest
```

and my tomcat dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I suspect that `spring-boot:run` has forked a second JVM and Eclipse doesn't shut them both down correctly. I'd take Maven out of the picture completely by running your main class directly in Eclipse rather than running it via Eclipse's Maven integration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve this problem, change `tomcat maven plugin` and add `fork` to `false`

```
   <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <fork>false</fork>
        </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Comment: Although this worked by not forking, I ran into other dependency conflicts. I just right clicked on my main class and `Run As > Java App`. When you stop, tomcat stops.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this bat script command:

`FOR /F "tokens=5 delims= " %%P IN ('netstat -a -n -o ^| findstr :8080.*LISTENING') DO TaskKill.exe /PID %%P /F
pause`
and saved it in `killport.bat`, then called it with maven-antrun-plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.6</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <configuration>
                <target>
                    <exec executable="cmd.exe" spawn="true">
                        <arg value="/c" />
                        <arg value="F:\Java\Projects\killport.bat" />
                    </exec>
                </target>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the    following Tag in to the spring-boot-maven-plugin in the pom.xml file

```
            <configuration>
                <fork>false</fork>
            </configuration>
```

here is the full Example :

```
    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <fork>false</fork>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
```